# Reconfiguration of FPGA in ML605 Board- THe ICAP IS NOT WORKING

Tags: fpga, verilog

The aim of my project is to load 3 bitstreams into the PROM; according to our requirement we load the 1or second or 3 bit file.

**PROBLEM FACING: THe problem is I'm unable to know whether the ICAP module is getting instantiated or not , if so the bit file is not loading from the desired address...why ?? 
And is there any process to Debug the ICAP module to know what address is going to the ICAP module  ???????**

The way i approached to the problem statement is :

Initially I have taken 2 trigger inputs, depending on it the 2 or 3 bit file will be loaded.. as the default one would be the First bit file (User Logic).

USER LOGIC : Explanation

First I have instantiated the ICAP Virtex 6 primitive, secondly, I have written a State machine in which I'm sending few IPROGRAM command sequence.

The IPROGRAM Command sequence consists of Warm Boot starting address and I have given the Address of the 2nd Bit file and also 3rd . and loading it.

My problem is, the state machine is working but the 2nd Bit or 3 bit file is not being loaded...I'm not sure even the ICAP is searching the PROM for the 2nd bitstream.....I have seen the example design files provided by the xilinx..but it was of no help

Here, I'm adding the code which I have coded.. Thank you

```
 module test_1(
     I0,
     I1,
     TRIGGER,
     status,
     A
        );
    input I0;
    input I1;
    input TRIGGER;
    output reg [7:0] status;
    output reg [3:0] A;


        wire clk;


        parameter[3:0] STATE_00 = 0;
        parameter[3:0] STATE_01 = 1;
        parameter[3:0] STATE_02 = 2;
        parameter[3:0] STATE_03 = 3;
        parameter[3:0] STATE_04 = 4;
        parameter[3:0] STATE_05 = 5;
        parameter[3:0] STATE_06 = 6;
        parameter[3:0] STATE_07 = 7;
        parameter[3:0] STATE_08 = 8;
        parameter[3:0] STATE_09 = 9;
        parameter[3:0] STATE_10 = 10;
        parameter[3:0] STATE_11 = 11;
        reg[3:0] NEXT_STATE = STATE_03;// STATE_00;
        reg CE =  1'b1;
        reg[31:0] I = 32'bZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ;;
        reg ICAP_WRITE = 1'b1;
       reg [1:0] counter;
        reg clock_2mhz_out;
        reg switch=1'b0;



    //      //---------Differential Clock---------------------------------------------

            // BUFGMUX: Global Clock Mux Buffer
            //          Virtex-6
            // Xilinx HDL Language Template, version 14.4

     IBUFGDS #(
          .DIFF_TERM("FALSE"), // Differential Termination
          .IOSTANDARD("DEFAULT") // Specifies the I/O standard for this buffer
       ) IBUFGDS_inst (
          .O(clk),  // Clock buffer output
          .I(I0),  // Diff_p clock buffer input
          .IB(I1) // Diff_n clock buffer input
       );


        //--------------------------------------------------------------------------

    //----------------ICAP PRIMITIVE--------------------------------------------
       // ICAP_VIRTEX6: Internal Configuration Access Port
       //               Virtex-6
       // Xilinx HDL Language Template, version 14.4

       ICAP_VIRTEX6 #(
          .DEVICE_ID(32'h04244093),                      // Specifies the pre-programmed Device ID value
          .ICAP_WIDTH("X32"),                  // Specifies the input and output data width to be used with the
                                                                // ICAP_VIRTEX6.
          .SIM_CFG_FILE_NAME("NONE")             // Specifies the Raw Bitstream (RBT) file to be parsed by the simulation
                                              // model
       )
       ICAP_VIRTEX6_inst (
          .BUSY(),                                                           // 1-bit output: Busy/Ready output
          .O(),                                                              // 32-bit output: Configuration data output bus
          .CLK(clk),                                                        // 1-bit input: Clock Input
          .CSB(CE),                                                     // 1-bit input: Active-Low ICAP input Enable
          .I(I),                                                           // 32-bit input: Configuration data input bus
          .RDWRB(ICAP_WRITE)                                            // as of now the write operation is 0
                                                                                // 1-bit input: Read/Write Select input
       );

       // End of ICAP_VIRTEX6_inst instantiation

        always@(negedge clk)
        begin
         if(TRIGGER == 1'b1)
         begin
         switch<=1'b1;
         end
    end

        always@(negedge clk)
        begin
             if(switch == 1'b1)
          begin
            case(NEXT_STATE)

                STATE_03:
                    begin
                        ICAP_WRITE <= 1'b0;
                        CE <= 1'b0;
                        status <= 8'h4;
                        I <= 32'hFFFFFFFF;
                        NEXT_STATE <= STATE_04;
                    end
                STATE_04:
                    begin
                        ICAP_WRITE <= 1'b0;
                        CE <= 1'b0;
                        status <= 8'h5;
                         I  <= 32'h5599AA66;
                        NEXT_STATE <= STATE_05;
                    end
                STATE_05:
                    begin
                        ICAP_WRITE <= 1'b0;
                        CE <= 1'b0;
                        status <= 8'h6;
                        I <= 32'h0400_0000;
                        NEXT_STATE <= STATE_06;
                    end
                STATE_06:
                    begin
                        ICAP_WRITE <= 1'b0;
                        CE <= 1'b0;
                        status <= 8'h7;
                        I <= 32'h0C40_0080;
                        NEXT_STATE <= STATE_07;
                    end
    THE SECONF BIT FILE IS NOT BEING ADDED...SO THE OUTPUT IS NOT COMING...
 THE SECONG BIT FILE CONSISTS OF A 1'BIT LED...WHICH I CONNECTED IT TO A GPIO    
                    STATE_07:
                        begin
                            ICAP_WRITE <= 1'b0;
                            CE <= 1'b0;
                            status <= 8'hff;
                            I <= 32'h3062CE59; The address i got when I'm lOADING THE pROM FILE
                            A <= 4'b1010;
                            NEXT_STATE <= STATE_08;
                        end
                    STATE_08:
                        begin
                            ICAP_WRITE <= 1'b0;
                            CE <= 1'b0;
                            status <= 8'h9;
                            I <= 32'h0C00_0180;     
                            NEXT_STATE <= STATE_09;
                        end
                    STATE_09:
                        begin
                            ICAP_WRITE <= 1'b0;
                            CE <= 1'b0;
                            status <= 8'hA;
                            I <= 32'h000000F0;
                            NEXT_STATE <= STATE_10;
                        end
                    STATE_10:
                        begin
                            ICAP_WRITE <= 1'b0;
                            CE <= 1'b0;
                            status <= 8'hB;
                            I <= 32'h04000000;
                            NEXT_STATE <=STATE_00 ;
                        end
                    STATE_11:
                        begin
                            ICAP_WRITE <= 1'b0;
                            CE <= 1'b1;
                            status <= 8'hC;
                            I <= 32'h00000000;
                            NEXT_STATE <= STATE_11;
                        end
                    default:
                        begin
                        ICAP_WRITE <= 1'b1;
                            CE <= 1'b1;
                            status <= 8'hD;
                            I <= 32'hAAAAAAAA;
                            NEXT_STATE <= STATE_00;
                        end
                    endcase
              end
              end
              else
              begin
                    ICAP_WRITE <= 1'b1;
                    CE <= 1'b1;
                    status <= 8'hE;
                    I <= 32'hAAAABBBB;
                    NEXT_STATE <= STATE_00;
              end
            end

        endmodule
```

Answer (score 1):

Is there a simulation model of the ICAP?  If so, debug it in simulation first.

If not, hang a chipscope off the ICAP signals so you can check they are doing the right thing.  And hang a scope/logic analyser off the external flash device's pins so you can see what the FPGA is doing and whether it is attempting to find and load the code you expect.

Write down for yourself what you expect to see on each of those interfaces and check it against reality.

Comment: I tried to add the Chipscope but Some of the Signals are not showing in the Chipscope.. I tried the Logic analyzer, it is showing fine..

Comment: When you say the LA is "showing fine" do you mean the FPGA and flash memory are doing everything you expect to see?  If so, then either it's working, or your understanding is incorrect.  If the latter, than write down carefully what you are understanding and what you are seeing and maybe post a detailed question to establish where your understanding is wrong...